# Convert Latex Code Parameter to a Text Representation for PackageWarning?

Tags: warnings, parameters

Consider the following MWE.  This is causing all kind of errors depending of the content of #1.

How can I convert #1 to a string representation (e.g. strip off or ignore textbf), so I can feed this to PackageWarning?

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{
   \PackageWarning{Error detected, while processing. Text representation: #1}
}
\begin{document}
   \mycommand{This is some text \textbf{why is this going wrong?}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't the `\textbf` but that `\PackageWarning` takes two parameters while you are only giving it one. This causes the command to take the following `\end` as the second parameter which causes a lot of trouble.

So just add the missing first parameter (representing the package name) to the macro call:

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{
   \PackageWarning{mypackage}{Error detected, while processing. Text representation: #1}
}
```

which will give the desired output

> Package mypackage Warning: Error detected, while processing. Text representation: This is some text \textbf {why is this going wrong?} on input line 7.